# What does it mean for my manuscript if the publisher's website says "decision letter being prepared"?

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper to Physics of Plasmas. After 101 
days the current stage says

> decision letter being prepared.

And there is bold sentence saying

> **days to render final decision 101.**

My question is:

1. Has the journal already made a decision regarding the paper or is the review process ongoing? Because not once it came to me for review.
2. Acceptance in one go is rare so does it mean a rejection?

Comment: Just be patient or ask the editor. He is the only one who knows.

Comment: What do you mean by *because not once it came to me for review?* Did you expect to review your own paper?

Comment: I also suggest that you take a look at: [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/7734)

Comment: I mean that the first decision report has not come yet, generally when a paper gets reviewed a report is generated and shared with an author. It went for a review and after the review by referee suddenly the status shows " preparing decision report" and the day counter which counts the number of days since submission says" days to render final decision 101 ", so I am wondering whether it's possible that a final decision has been reached without the review being shared with me, will it be a minor or major revision or is it that they have rejected it.

Answer (score -1):

In all likelihood, if a decision has been made without reviews, the handling editor did not find the paper suitable for the journal and has chosen to not even start the review process. My money would be on a rejection.

It is fairly normal that editors do a screening of the paper before the review process starts to avoid wasting reviewers time on papers that are almost certain to be rejected.

Comment: No but the paper went for a review as the status shoes review stated and review received

Comment: It hasn't come to me even once till now , I mean that I haven't received even the result of the first round of review and the status is saying : days to final decision 101

Comment: Hopefully, rejection mail is on the way.